# Kill process without knowing the full path using Qt

Tags: qt, qprocess

I'm trying to retrieve the active processes on my computer and to search for specific one,
if it exists then i should kill it.
Is it possible to do it without knowing the specific path of the execute? 
I know the execute process name but not the full path.

So in short:

1. Get all active processes.
2. Kill specific process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no Qt-specific way to do what you want, so you have to use native platform API. Which platform (Widnows, Unix, MacOS) are you interested in?

EDIT:
Take a look at MSDN process functions reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684847(v=VS.85).aspx , especially EnumProcesses, OpenProcess and TerminateProcess. I won't give you any code snippets, since I haven't used this API myself (I just have it bookmarked).

Answer (score 0):

like it was said, you could do it for windows relatively easy using win api: [Enumerating All Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623(v=VS.85).aspx) && [Terminating a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686722(v=VS.85).aspx)

for linux you could try running smth like "ps -A" using [QProcess](http://gutenberg.trolltech.kunder.linpro.no/4.6/qprocess.html) and parse its standard output; smth like this:

```
QProcess process;
process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
process.start("ps",  QStringList() << "-A");
if (!process.waitForStarted())
    return;
if (!process.waitForFinished())
    return;

//qDebug() << process.readAll();    
QByteArray output = process.readLine().trimmed();
while (!output.isEmpty())
{
    qDebug() << output;
    QList<QByteArray> items = output.split(' ');
    qDebug() << "pid:" << items.first() << " cmd:" << items.last();
    qDebug() << "===============================================";
    output = process.readLine().trimmed();
}
```

this should return a list of running processes, you could try different command line options for [ps](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ps.htm) to get the data you need. I believe killing the process could be done the same ways; by running [kill](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_kill.htm) [pid]

hope this would give you an idea on how to proceed, regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MacOS or BSD you can list all the processes using the [sysctl API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html).

On Linux it seems the best you can do is look at how it's done in the [source code to ps](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/proc/readproc.h?revision=1.37&view=markup), which is basically to navigate the [`/proc` file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs).